# How to mount Docker MySQL Data/Socket volume on Windows 10?

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, windows-container

I'm trying to simply run the latest docker mysql image on windows 10 with a data directory from the host mounted.

I'm running

```
docker run --rm --name=mysql --mount type=bind,src="C:\Docker Projects\mysql\mysql_data",dst=/var/lib/mysql mysql/mysql-server
```

But it's complaining about a socket not being present.

```
2020-01-20T17:23:22.758269Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010270] [Server] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Operation not permitted
2020-01-20T17:23:22.758416Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010258] [Server] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock ?
```

I can see a mysql mysql.sock.lock is created. I've also tried creating a mysql.sock file from the host.

I think this is telling me I need to specify where the socket file is for windows https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/deploy-mysql-nonlinux-docker.html but I can't seem to get the command syntax right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. The problem is that the mysql.sock file got put into /var/lib/mysql, which is mounted into a Windows host system directory that does not support Unix domain sockets.

Just use switch `--socket=/tmp/mysql.sock` when starting the server.

Answer (score 2):

2022 update
If you want to have a persistent database for docker(Windows) MySQL using docker Hyper-V

1. Make a folder at any location where you want to have your DB data
   for eg. D:\DockerDB
2. Now, use Docker in Hyper-v mode.
3. Go to settings -> Resources -> File sharing -> add you DB data folder here.(D:\DockerDB) and apply and restart.
   [image]

In your docker-compose.yml file add volumes as below

```
mysqldb:
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - D:/DockerDB:/var/lib/mysql
```

Now your data will persist on DB on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this to work for docker-compose, you can use the following `docker-compose.yml` and `my.cnf` file.

In the my.cnf file the socket location is changed from `socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` to `socket=/tmp/mysql.sock`.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7.27
    volumes:
      - "./my.cnf:/etc/my.cnf"
```

**my.cnf**

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html

[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
secure-file-priv=/var/lib/mysql-files
user=mysql

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```